# Magento 1.7 Create Order Controller Error

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I recently upgraded to Magento 1.7.0.2 and when I try to create an order in the admin panel I a 500 server error and this is logged:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::setSkipSaleableCheck() in /var/www/vhosts/dev.mydomain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php on line 45, referer: https://dev.mydomain.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/5da67d5b8c41312785d474f556dbfb7f/`

Haven't been able to find anyone with similar issues yet...Any ideas?

Comment: First things first; do you have a method named setSkipSaleableCheck in the file /var/www/vhosts/dev.mydomain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php?

Comment: Yes, I have that method in that file

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same problem. Anyone have ideas?

Hey Miles: I found the solution after some massive hunting...
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/205818/#t324666

WarehouseMultimedia's post is what helped. The php.ini change is what did the trick. I never edited the .htaccess file and it was working. I was also on version 1.7 and it the solution still worked.

"...

I fixed this by increasing memory_limit & max_execution_time settings in both php.ini & .htaccess:

php.ini

```
memory_limit = 256M

max_execution_time = 18000
```

.htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 256M

php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

"

This appears to be an issue that is unique to bluehost. Are you using bluehost?

Comment: You certainly don't need a max execution time of 18000 seconds (that is five hours!)

Comment: Shrug... who knows the programmatic intent of WarehouseMultimedia's code. Just re-quoting it here as a relevant solution for the problem at hand.

Comment: Yay! I'm not alone! Thanks for posting. I'll check into this and get back to you. I'm on Rackspace.

Comment: My values were already set to what you have above. I tried increasing them even more and am still running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have Magento 1.7.0.2 installed and this error should not happen! It is possible that the upgrade missed some of Magento core code. How did you upgrade it?

This error message says that the class Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product (~/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php) does not contain the method "setSkipSaleableCheck". In my copy of v1.7.0.2 I do have this method.

Open ~/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php and search for "public function setSkipSaleableCheck($skipSaleableCheck = false)". If this method definition does not exists, then download a vanilla version of Magento 1.7.0.2 and replace this file.

This should fix the missing method only.

Comment: Yes, I have that function `public function setSkipSaleableCheck($skipSaleableCheck = false)`

Comment: Then your problem is something else. Clear all of the Magento cache and make sure the following directory are empty (~/var/cache ~/var/report  ~/var/session). Then enable error reporting by renaming the file (~/errors/local.xml.sample to local.xml). Then re-test your site. What error messages do you get?

Make sure you disable error reporting after you have finished testing. Rename local.xml to local.xml.sample.

Comment: I renamed errors/local.xml, but where are these errors logged? When I try to create an order on the backend, I still see the same error page: `Server 500 error: The website encountered an error while retrieving http://mydomain.localhost/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/start/key/372b9af2b85fa77c27c46e7106506af4/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.` and I still see the same error mentioned in my question in the server log.

Comment: Weird, I'm not seeing any file/folder named report in /var/

Comment: Create it and make sure it is writable for Magento source code.